# Yarp integration with Dapr

Tags: .net-core, dapr, ms-yarp

I want to integrate YARP with DAPR.
My use case is that when a user hits the yarp URL, the downstream of it must invoke the DAPR sidecar URL for service invocation
Eg.

```
http(s)://<Yarp service >/api/< service name >/XXXXX (Upstream)
 To 
http://<Dapr-sidecar>/v1.0/invoke/< service name >/method/XXXXX (Downstream)
```

I'm not sure how I configure this as YARP routes.

Please help.

Comment: What did you try